# How do I pass the user's input from my .html file to my .c file?

Tags: html, forms, user-input

I'm trying to get the input from my html webpage, which has a text box and submit button. How can I get the user's input in a separate .c file, so that I can change what happens in my html file depending on the input?

Comment: `answer.c` definitely is not the way to call a CGI program. Read about CGI programs and how your web server handles them, then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

What is that *.c program? 
If a server can not parse this Code, then it will Show the Code as text.

E.g.: If you will run a *.php script without PHP-Parser on the server, it would not work.